# Helm inheritance on value file from a generic value file

Tags: templates, kubernetes-helm

I have the following example of the structure I am trying to achieve in helm, to get variables in the value file from a 3rd value file:

### template.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: "{{ include "test-chart.fullname" . }}-test-connection"
  labels:
    {{- include "test-chart.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": test
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicas }}
  restartPolicy: Never
```

### values.yaml

```
replicas: {{ (I need to get replica value from the values-generic.yaml) }}
```

### values-generic.yaml

```
replicas: 8
```

And I create a template with the following command:

> helm template  .  --values .\templates\values\values.yaml --output-dir './yamls'

I have tried solutions as:

```
{{- $generic:= .Files.Get "../generic-values.yaml" | fromYaml }}
replicas: {{ $generic.replicas }}
```

or

```
{{- include .. }}
```

but they dont seem to be working are they have effect only in template file and not in value file.

***To be mentioned that I am trying to avoid to pass an another value file into helm template command**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Adding a `helm template -f ../values-generic.yaml` option will be far easier than what you're trying to do; why is that not an option?

Comment: (You are tripping over at least two problems, that you can't use Helm templating markup inside values files and that you can't access files outside the chart directory.  In theory it's possible to do something like this, but you'd have to use an option like `--set-string moreValues=$(cat ../values-generic.yaml)` and a very roundabout path every time you wanted to use a value from it.)

Comment: Hi David and thanks for your answer. I dont want to pass 2 value files into the helm template command because I am handing this to several teams and I cant control what commands they run. The "helm template.." command should be 1 and unchanged. But the value.yaml files should be using different env variables depends the team. Both your answers are suggesting to pass more variables into the "helm template" command if I understand correctly, which is something that I am trying to avoid

Comment: What is the higher-level goal you're trying to achieve?  The "generic" values file suggests to me that you might want to put those default values in the chart's `values.yaml` file and not somewhere external.  Anything the deployment team adds via their own `-f` or `--set` options will override those values.

Comment: The main problem here is that we have more than 40 value files (equal to the envs we deploy our k8s) (and also this number increases every week). the value files hold some values that are shared to all of them with a tag like "prod" & "devtest". So my idea is to make two templates "prod" & "devtest" with the common values and refer to these templates from my value files to make the maintenance easier.